# batch for "%var%" %%g in example.txt do save=%%g

Tags: bash, loops, batch-file, for-loop

Yesterday a friend of mine give me this code what extracts a line from a file. 
I don't know how it really works, and I need to port it to bash.

```
@echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set list="List_of_pages.txt"
    :: Count lines and generate number
    for /f "usebackq" %%c in (`find /V /C "" ^< %list%`) do set lines=%%c
    set /a chosen = 0
    :AA
    set /a chosen = %chosen% +1
    set /a skiplines= %chosen% -1

    if chosen equ lines goto eof
    :: gets the line
    set skip=
    if %skiplines% gtr 0 set skip=skip=%skiplines%


       for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%c in (%list%) do set "current=%%c" & goto continue

        :continue
    echo  %current%
```

Now, what does `for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%c in (%list%) do set "current=%%c" & goto continue` mean? What i really don't know what is is that `%skip%`

Any help though of how that line could be in bash?

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/

Answer (score 0):

Please, Note these basics of batch... which will keep you running to easily convert batch scripts to bash.

- All the strings enclosed within **%** Symbols are Variables. (E.g. %Variable%)
- **Set** is a command used to assign a value to a variable. (or to initialize a variable)
- **For** is a Loop command - and, you must know the work of loop.
- The Sub Commands of **For** command (loop) - UseBackQ, Skip, Delims.

**UseBackQ:** tells the CMD that, inside **FOR LOOP** parenthesis, there will be string - if that atring is enclosed by "" (double quotes) then it is a filename (not a simple string), and modifies the usage of ` (ticks) too.
**Skip:** Tells CMD to skip First **N** Number of lines from a Text file (It will not read those lines)
**Delims:** tells from where you want to chop a string (line of file) - e.g. **Delims=,** will seperate lines into pieces from all commas.

**My Analysis:**
Here, I think - what this code will do is to take a file, and Return one line of that text file as selected by user.

It is reading a file **List_of_pages.txt** in line ***5***. And, it should be **Set /p Skip=** @Line 12. (Don't count empty lines). And, Returning The selected line @line **14**.

Hope, I helped! :)